# Using react-hook-form, how can I wait to execute conditional logic on changes until after any existing data is loaded from the database?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have two select fields: a country field with consistent options, and a state field with options determined by what is selected for the country field like so:

```
  const { resetField, watch } = useFormContext();
  const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);

  const countryValue = watch("Country");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`"Using formContext changed to ${countryValue}!"`);
    resetField("State", { defaultValue: null });
    if (!countryValue) {
      setOptions([]);
    } else {
      if (countryValue === "US") {
        setOptions(["AL", "CA", "GA", "TX"]);
      } else if (countryValue === "CA") {
        setOptions(["AB", "BC", "FE"]);
      } else {
        setOptions([]);
      }
    }
  }, [resetField, countryValue]);
```

I'm also loading saved data for these fields from an API. This saved data can be null, or it can have previous user selections.

I'm having an issue where if I load existing data for these two fields, setting the country field with this existing data causes the useEffect to execute, and the saved data is cleared from the state field. Any suggestions for how to get around this?

Was able to reproduce the issue in codesandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-paper-47qmvk?file=/src/App.js

I've tried adding a timeout to delay rendering the fields, but I think because I am registering the fields through the defaultValues prop like so:

```
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [existingInfo, setExistingInfo] = useState({
    Country: null,
    State: null
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    // Simulating an API
    setTimeout(() => {
      setExistingInfo({ Country: "US", State: "AL" });
      setTimeout(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      }, 1000);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  const contextForm = useForm({
    defaultValues: useMemo(() => existingInfo, [existingInfo])
  });
```

and then using useFormContext(), the change is detected anyway.